# Iteration over n values

Tags: python, algorithm

I'd like to make an iteration to calculate all the possibilities of a given formula. I need to write down nested iteration but couldn't make it right. I am not good at algorithm :(

For calculating all the possibilities(%0-%100) 3 constant{z1,z2,z3} values, I prepared:

```
a=frange(0,1.0,0.01)
for z1 in a:
  for z2 in a:
    for z3 in a:
      calculate(z1,z2,z3)
```

and works properly as I expected.

If z is a list which consists of n values(n can be 2-30 in my case), Which algorithm do you suggest to me to handle this? How can I create nested iteration?

Comment: Like that. Or is this a trick question?

Comment: @Ignacio: I bet when we see it we're gonna be all like "Doh!".

Comment: indeed, if that works properly, what else do you need!?

Comment: S/he wants something that generalizes nicely to larger values of 3, without requiring different code for each number of copies and hugely-nested loops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `itertools.product()`:

```
a=frange(0,1.0,0.01)
for z in itertools.product(a, repeat=n):
    calculate(*z)
```

If `n` really would be `30`, this would iterate over `100**30 = 10**60` values.  Be prepared to wait.

Comment: I  even didn't know such a module exists :) Thanks a lot, python is great.

Comment: Sven, any meaning to put * in front of z calculate(*z) ? Calculation is not a big deal, thanks.

Comment: @Fish: If yoou'd know that `n` is `3`, you could write `for z1, z2, z3 in itertools.product(...)`.  Since you don't know `n` in advance, you can't use sequence unpacking, and `z` is the tuple of all parameters.  I assume `calculate()` takes `n` parameters, and unpack the tuple on calling `calculate()`.

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.product` will do what you want (and more). Unfortunately it wants the lists whose products it computes in separate arguments, like this:

```
>>> list(itertools.product([1,2,3],[1,2,3]))
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

so on the face of it you need to do something like this:

```
a=frange(0,1.0,0.01)
for (z1,z2,z3) in itertools.product(a,a,a): calculate(z1,z2,z3)
```

but if you want to use the exact code for different numbers of products you can say

```
a=frange(0,1.0,0.01)
for (z1,z2,z3) in itertools.product(*(3*[a])): calculate(z1,z2,z3)
```

or

```
a=frange(0,1.0,0.01)
for (z1,z2,z3) in apply(itertools.product, 3*[a]): calculate(z1,z2,z3)
```

Comment: (Sven M. posted his answer while I was writing mine. His is better because he knew about the `repeat` kwarg for `itertools.product` and I didn't. I'm leaving mine here instead of deleting it just in case the extra verbosity is helpful to anyone.)